# Signal.welch function: f and pxx outcome is 0

Tags: python, frequency

I have an array of BOLD activity of length 240. A recording took place every 2 seconds (you can download a part of the data [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rkK3K3wGQ52lulNVUDlIX5bIrT0P6KO3/view?usp=sharing) (the file can be opend normally with a .txt editor). I want to analyse this time series with the signal.welch function.

```
f, pxx = signal.welch(data, fs=0.5, window='hanning', nperseg=50, noverlap=25, scaling='density', average='mean')
```

It gives me the following error

> ValueError: noverlap must be less than nperseg.

When I set `noverlap = None` , no error shows up, but f equals 0 and pxx is an array of 0s.

Thank you very much for your suggestions!!

Comment: You code works with no errors when I run it. It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the data file with, for example,

```
data = np.loadtxt('rest1_LeftInsula.1D')
```

`data` will be a 1-d numpy array with shape (240,), and the call

```
f, pxx = signal.welch(data, fs=0.5, window='hanning', nperseg=50, noverlap=25, scaling='density', average='mean')
```

works with no errors.

If I reshape `data` to be an array with shape (240, 1), and pass that to `welch` (which can be done by indexing it as `data[:, None]` or with the reshape method `data.reshape((240, 1))`), I get the same error that you reported:

```
In [11]: f, pxx = signal.welch(data[:,None], fs=0.5, window='hanning', nperseg=5, 0, noverlap=25, scaling='density', average='mean')
[...]/scipy/signal/spectral.py:1964: UserWarning: nperseg = 50 is greater than input length  = 1, using nperseg = 1
  warnings.warn('nperseg = {0:d} is greater than input length '
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-0e5235350cfd> in <module>
----> 1 f, pxx = signal.welch(data[:,None], fs=0.5, window='hanning', nperseg=50, noverlap=25, scaling='density', average='mean')

[...]/scipy/signal/spectral.py in welch(x, fs, window, nperseg, noverlap, nfft, detrend, return_onesided, scaling, axis, average)
    446 
    447     """
--> 448     freqs, Pxx = csd(x, x, fs=fs, window=window, nperseg=nperseg,
    449                      noverlap=noverlap, nfft=nfft, detrend=detrend,
    450                      return_onesided=return_onesided, scaling=scaling,

[...]/scipy/signal/spectral.py in csd(x, y, fs, window, nperseg, noverlap, nfft, detrend, return_onesided, scaling, axis, average)
    580 
    581     """
--> 582     freqs, _, Pxy = _spectral_helper(x, y, fs, window, nperseg, noverlap, nfft,
    583                                      detrend, return_onesided, scaling, axis,
    584                                      mode='psd')

[...]/scipy/signal/spectral.py in _spectral_helper(x, y, fs, window, nperseg, noverlap, nfft, detrend, return_onesided, scaling, axis, mode, boundary, padded)
   1756         noverlap = int(noverlap)
   1757     if noverlap >= nperseg:
-> 1758         raise ValueError('noverlap must be less than nperseg.')
   1759     nstep = nperseg - noverlap
   1760 

ValueError: noverlap must be less than nperseg.
```

The problem is that, by default, `welch` is applied along the *last* axis of the input array. If that array has shape (240, 1), `welch` attempts to apply the calculation to each "row" of the 2-d array.  But each row has length 1, which is too small for the given values of `nperseg` and `noverlap`, and that leads to the (somewhat cryptic) error.

You haven't shown how you read the file and created `data`, but I suspect it is creating an array (or some other data structure, such as a Pandas DataFrame) that has shape (240, 1).

To fix this, you can "flatten" the data into a 1-d array (e.g. pass `data.ravel()` to `welch`), or pass the argument `axis=0` to `welch` to tell it to act along the first dimension instead of the last.  If you do the latter, be aware that the shape of `pxx` will be (26, 1), instead of the shape (26,) that you get when `data` has shape (240,).